# Resources$NotFoundException when running 1.6 application on Android 2.0

Tags: android

I've created very simple project to show the issue I'm facing. There is one activity created by default. With one additional line of code in onCreate method:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample);
```

Sample referes to "sample.png" file, which I've put in drawable-hdpi, -mdpi, -ldpi. Project is defined with minSdkVersion="4" (Android 1.6).

When I run this application on Android 2.0 Emulator, I get Resources$NotFoundException. On Android 1.6 Emulator everything works fine.

Please help.

EDIT: It looks like projects created with SDK v.1.6. won't run on 2.0 system. Does anyone has similar problem? Or maybe you simply don't use SDK from version 1.6?

Comment: what version is the android 2.0 sdk?

Comment: I'm not sure is this what you're asking for, but it is "Android SDK Platform 2.0, revision 1". I've downloaded all SDKs on 03/11/2010.

Comment: this is strange, change your sample.png to icon.png, then let's see if it is able to get that........

Comment: I already have icon.png in each drawable directory. This file is created by default, while creating new Android Project in Eclipse.
I've changed getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon) and got the same error.

And btw: that same application created with Android 2.0 SDK works on Android 2.0.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you found a solution yet?